# Check POST request payload data with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

Let's say i have angular page with a couple of input elements and save button.
After Save button is clicked POST request will be sent.
I'm writing Protractor e2e test for this page.

**The question:**

How can i check with protractor POST request payload data after app is sent it or before sending?
I want to be sure that my app will sent right data in POST request.

Comment: I would recommend you to write a unit test for that using Karma and Jasmine. You don't need protractor to test that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Andres D's comment: yes, there is a misconception here.

`protractor` is a tool that helps you mimic real-user interactions with a page by automating a real browser. It stays on the high-level, sees what a normal user can see - click buttons, fills out inputs etc.

In other words, it is a black box testing, it doesn't matter where is data coming from, which protocol used to transfer it or how many external js files your page requires to be loaded - these are all technical details that should checked and tested separately.

---

FYI, there is a relevant tool called [`protractor-http-mock`](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) that can help you in testing corner cases allowing to replace the server responses with custom defined.