# Asserting $http request payloads without mocking them

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm writing Protractor tests to verify the successful creation of reports in our application. A report is created via a series of complex UI interactions within a dialog and saved via an AJAX POST request to a REST API.

I've written tests for the complex UI interactions within the modal, but I'm at a loss for how to test the POST request within the same Protractor tests. Ideally, I'd like to be able to make assertions against the payload of the POST request to verify that the UI is sending the correct data to the API.

It's important to note that I do not want to mock the HTTP call--I need it to go through, since subsequent protractor tests navigate to the report and perform additional checks. My first thought was to somehow hook into the $httpBackend.passThrough() method, but I haven't had any success with that.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think this is something you need to use `protractor` for. Unit-test it instead.

Comment: @alecxe How would you unit test the UI to make sure it's creating the correct request payload? I need a functional/integration test here to ensure that even CSS changes don't break functionality.

Comment: Please see, related: [Check POST request payload data with Protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428874/check-post-request-payload-data-with-protractor).

Comment: Based on the linked SO question, I would need to use something like [protractor-http-mock's `requestsMade()`](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock#inspection). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since subsequent protractor tests navigate to the report and perform additional checks

If you check that the report contains data to that matches which was submitted, you are, albeit indirectly, testing that the POST went through successfully. There is a reasonable argument that this is enough for the E2E test: it tests that the application behaves as he user would want. The user doesn't care how it's achieved: POST, websockets, carrier pigeon ;-)

Keep in mind that the usual aim of such tests is for them to fail if something is broken. If the POST isn't done correctly, then the subsequent tests that verify the displayed report would fail.

The downside is that you would have a bit less information about what has gone wrong than if you managed to test the POST as well. However, unit tests can help. If you have a failing unit test that localises the issue, you write a fix that makes it pass. If you don't have a failing unit test, you can investigate the issue by debugging, add a failing test that highlights the issue, and fix the code so it passes.

Comment: Coincidentally, I arrived at this same conclusion: the functional test shouldn't care about the POST request and should only test the UI. I've added separate unit tests for the POST request.